# Product of two functions in $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Can you help me proving the following statement?

> Let $u,v \in H^1(I)$ where $I$ is an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $u \cdot v \in H^1(I)$ and $(u\cdot v)^\prime = (u^\prime \cdot v) + (u \cdot v^\prime)$.

Comment: What do you know about functions in $H^1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note that the space $H^1(I)$ is the space of absolutely continuous functions with weak derivative in $L^2(I)$. Hence the product is still absolutely continuous and the Leibniz formula holds.

Hint for higher dimensions: if one of the two functions is assumed to be $C_{c}^{\infty}$, then by Mayer and Serrin (or sometimes it is taken as a definition), for every element $u \in H^{k}$ there exists a sequence of $C^{\infty}$ functions that converge to $u$. Then it’s all about using the properties for smooth functions (which hold) and then pass to the limit.

Comment: The result is false in dimensions $d>1$ for $H^1$, one needs $H^k$ with $k>d/2$.

Comment: True, I missed to add one function must be regular enough (in the version I wanted to mention)! Thanks a lot!